# My network password for my wifi

Tags: ipad

I cannot remember my network wifi password to set up another device.  Is there a way to see the password on my iPad since it is connected to my personal wifi?

Comment: What brand is your router? It might be LinkSys or Belkin... The brand will be on the actual router. I can walk you through how to get the password from the router, if need be.

Comment: @Frysk, That's assuming Leda remembers the password to the router! :)

Comment: True, true. But I figured we could start with the default username and password for the router. Maybe they didn't change it when they set it up.

Comment: Answer to the question is "No. You should have written it down." :/

Answer (score 0):

On the iPad there's no way of viewing your password but if you have a Mac running OS X Mavericks v10.9 or later and your iPad is running iOS 7.0.3 or later having your iCloud Keychain synced up with them both then you could see your password in your Mac's Keychain Access.

Follow [this Apple FAQ](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204085) about iCloud Keychain.